# Is this bug or why my model ruined in sculpting process?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

At first model had lost many peaces of topology and then holes filled with triangles other red color. (sorry for such english)
[image: I have just add reference image. (version LTS 2.92)]

Comment: Looks like some normals are pointing the wrong way. In edit mode try to select everything then SHIFT N or Mesh > Normals > Recalculate (outside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your normals are pointing the wrong way.

To fix this press:

1. <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything
2. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*
3. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals on the outside

Comment: Why does this happens?